# Running Brunch.io directly from node.js rather than CLI

Tags: javascript, node.js, brunch

I'm looking for an more efficient build-tool like gulp for huge Projects.

Brunch seems to be the thing for that, but I was wondering if I could run Brunch from an Node.js script, rather than the CLI.
The docs doesn't seem to have any detail on that….

Are there any plans or undocumented ways to archive this?

Comment: Hi, could you explain _why_ do you need this behavior? Probably, we I can help you to find a better solution.

Comment: We require a new build tool at work, mostly due to performance reasons, to generalize each project with an help-script for various reasons, which also controls the Front-End building. We generate the _final_ config dynamically, depending on what site on an CMS-Instance, which file-relations and on which Framework should be injected into the building of the wanted JS/CSS and other Assets. It's also considered what extensions of an CMS instance is active and whether or not leave out some files for page optimization.

Comment: It would be much better to just create the final config (which will be big) and give it brunch, rather than writing out the file, executing the command and then hoping the exit codes are right.

Comment: I don't understand why you can't just write you config once. You can use our Brunch's skeletons for generating them automatically, for example. Personally, I think there is something wrong with you idea. As I understand, you need some kind of JavaScript API.Anyway, give me a minute, I'm gonna describe our undocumented API that could help you.

Answer (score 0):

The reasons are still unclear for me, but anyway, here are two approaches that could fit your needs.

### init-skeleton

We have awesome package that is used in Brunch internally. It's called [init-skeleton](https://github.com/brunch/init-skeleton). You can write a skeleton for your needs and use that package for scaffolding.

This package has `init` method that could help you. It has this signature `init(skeleton[, options])`. The `skeleton` might be:

- Path to the skeleton in your file system
- Git URI
- GitHub URI (such as `gh:user/project`, `github:user/project`)

`options` are optional. There are these ones:

- `rootPath` — a string which is a root path of the result directory
- `commandName` — a string which is a command that will be used in [`printBanner` function](https://github.com/brunch/init-skeleton/blob/93f0d902b259cd99dc910e2209cb50f972cb4ddf/lib/print-banner.js).
- `logger` — a function that will be used for logging purposes.

For example:

```
const initSkeleton = require('init-skeleton').init

initSkeleton('path/to/skeleton')
  .then(() => {
    console.log('Done!')

    // do something else
    // ...
  })
```

If that's not you're looking for, then there is another solution — use Brunch JavaScript API.

### Brunch JavaScript API

Yeah, probably that's what you're looking for. Brunch has internal JavaScript API. This API isn't documented. This API could be changed (and apparently wile be), so be careful using this.

Probably, you've already noticed that Brunch's `package.json` have [`main` field that corresponds to `./lib/index`](https://github.com/brunch/brunch/blob/master/package.json#L32). This exports three methods (which actually correspond to [Brunch's commands](http://brunch.io/docs/commands)):

1. [`new` method](https://github.com/brunch/brunch/blob/1aebcbe4c4dd43b86fb7d148e00a6225049bae75/lib/index.js#L23-L36) scaffolds a new projects using `init-skeleton`.
2. [`build` method](https://github.com/brunch/brunch/blob/1aebcbe4c4dd43b86fb7d148e00a6225049bae75/lib/index.js#L50) runs Brunch for building project once.
3. [`watch` method](https://github.com/brunch/brunch/blob/1aebcbe4c4dd43b86fb7d148e00a6225049bae75/lib/index.js#L51) runs Brunch watcher for incremental builds.

`build` and `watch` might be useful for you. Both of them uses [`start` function](https://github.com/brunch/brunch/blob/1aebcbe4c4dd43b86fb7d148e00a6225049bae75/lib/index.js#L38-L48). This function is encapsulated for internal usage and has following signature: `start(persistent, arg2, arg3)`. Here:

- `presistent` is a boolean value that indicates should project build once or watch for changes.
- `arg2` is a path to the working directory (or `undefined` if not present). [It specified by `build [path]`](https://github.com/brunch/brunch/blob/1aebcbe4c4dd43b86fb7d148e00a6225049bae75/lib/cli.js#L36).
- `arg3` is always [a `Command` object](https://github.com/tj/commander.js/blob/master/index.js#L75-L89) provided by [commander.js](https://github.com/tj/commander.js).

Moreover, you can also require a `brunch/lib/cli` module. This module exports [a `run` method](https://github.com/brunch/brunch/blob/1aebcbe4c4dd43b86fb7d148e00a6225049bae75/lib/cli.js#L94-L116). This method doesn't take any argument. It just parses `process.argv` and runs the Brunch properly.

That's it. It may look like a hack, it does and it is. Be careful using it, because we are going to change that API in future. Keep in mind that these possibilities ***aren't documented***, so we ***won't warn you before changes***.

Try to find another solution for you problem. Sometimes problem appears not because of problem itself, but because of bad understanding of approach you use.

Hope this would help you.